# How do I create and append an image with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, append

I'm using the following code to create an image element, load it, then append it to the article on load.

```
$('<img />')
  .attr('src', 'image.png') //actually imageData[0].url
  .load(function () {
    $('article').append($(this));
    alert('image added');
  });
```

The alert is firing off ok, but the image doesn't appear, and when I inspect the element it has been added without the closing slash

```
<img src='image.png' >
```

Why is the browser removing the forward slash and how do I stop it?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to everyone who has pointed out that it's not the slash that's the problem (every day's a school day), so what could it be then? Here's the live example http://chris-armstrong.com/inspiration/?username=behoff

**UPDATE 2**:
Ok so it appears I'm a moron for not testing this with other images, as the issue seems to be with the test image I was using (http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/dc01f803819405bfe160459021cfe6cc57766f9b_m.jpg). Strange because it loads when you click on the URL... but anyway, thanks for all your help folks, I learned a few things!

Comment: Do you specify the correct path? Also you are not wrapping `image.png` in quotes.

Comment: The slash might not be required, depending on the document type. Also whatever tool you are using to inspect the document, it does not mean that it displays the DOM exactly as it is written. Does the image exist? You have to pass the value in a string: `.attr('src', 'image.png')` and maybe you have to add a slash before it: `.attr('src', '/image.png')`. Check the path.

Comment: I guess `article` is either an `id` or a `class`.. isn't it ??

Comment: @Avinash: Or the HTML5 `article` element.

Comment: @Avinash article is the HTML5 Article element

Comment: If you're getting the `alert()`, the image is loaded, and you state that you're able to inspect the element in the DOM. So are you sure it isn't just a CSS issue?

Comment: @sarfraz I've updated the example to have quotes, however I'm actually pulling my url's from a JSON array (see code comment) so the address is accurate

Comment: @Felix I'm using Chrome's inspector, and the path is accurate (when I copy and paste the url into another window it loads the correct image), the issue is that for some reason the forward slash on the img tag is being removed, so the tag isn't closed properly

Comment: @Chris Armstrong: I don't think this is the problem. If I inspect images here on SO (in Chrome), then no image has the slash. In HTML, the closing tags (and the self closing thingy) are more or less optional.

Comment: @Chris: If the closing `/` is being removed, it's being removed by the browser, not by jQuery. Use the same browser to inspect images here on StackOverflow. You should see the same thing. EDIT: *As @Felix also noted.*

Comment: Ultimate proof for the slash not being the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/6chCu/ Inspect the image.

Comment: @Felix point taken, thanks :D so what could it be?

Comment: @Chris: [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051437/how-do-i-create-and-append-an-image-with-javascript-jquery/5051625#5051625) Looks like a CSS issue to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information provided, we know the following:

- The image is successfully appended.
- The image is successfully loaded *(otherwise you wouldn't get the `alert()`)*.

Either you have an entirely transparent image *(not likely of course)*, or I'd bet that your CSS is somehow preventing its display.

**Here's an example using the CSS that you commented out in your demo.**

http://jsfiddle.net/JxhaR/ *(No visible image)*

Specifically, the culpret seems to be:

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

When I disable that, the image displays.

http://jsfiddle.net/JxhaR/1/ *(Image is visible.)*

Comment: Hah, thanks, as unlikely as it seems it turns out the test image (http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/dc01f803819405bfe160459021cfe6cc57766f9b_m.jpg) I was using seems to be the problem... when I tried with other images in the array they appear just fine. Bizarre though, because the image loads when you go to its url

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('<img />')
    .attr('src', 'image.png')
    .append('article')
    .load(function(){
        alert('image added');
    });
```

Comment: If any then it should be `appendTo`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm afraid that doesn't seem to append anything to the article

Comment: Ah, appendTo acts in the same way as my example, but again the image doesn't appear because the forward slash is removed.

Comment: @Chris Armstrong: You should read the comments. **It is not because of the slash.** The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Chris Armstrong, Felix King is right the missing slash is based on your doctype: HTML 4 and HTML5 do not use closing tags, XHTML does

Comment: @Felix just reading them all now, sorry. I've posted a link in response to Guffa's answer

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the element, you don't see it the way that it was added. Regardless if you add elements as HTML code or as elements (as in this case), when you inspect the code you are looking at code that was created from the element, you are not looking at the code that was used to add the element.

When you use `$('<img />')` it actually does a `document.createElement('img')`, so there is no HTML code where the ending slash can or can not be present. The element is created as a DOM object, it's not created from HTML code.

So, the reason that the image doesn't appear is not that there appears to be no ending slash in the tag.

The likely reason is that the image actually doesn't exist where the browser is looking for it, i.e. either the file is missing, or the URL is not correct.

Comment: The load event is firing, so the image must have been successfully loaded.

Comment: OK, I'll believe you that it's not the slash :D so what could it be? The life example is here http://chris-armstrong.com/inspiration/?username=behoff

Comment: @Chris Armstrong: When I test that in Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari the image shows up just fine.

Comment: @Chris Armstrong: I can see the image perfectly (in Chrome). But it only shows up *after* I click ok in the alert.